# How do I pass cookies when making a REST API call using PHP

Tags: php, rest, api, cookies

I am making an API call by passing an API Key

```
http://store12.com:8080/business?key=23122312
```

When I make this API call, it works great, I can access the business class using that api key.

But this API call is designed by storing cookies, so if I want to access another class

```
http://store12.com:8080/services?key=23122312 //won't work when no cookie stored
```

It won't work, as it requires a cookie, once I pass cookies, it will access it without an api key also

```
http://store12.com:8080/services //when cookie is stored, this works
```

This will work once cookies is stored.

Since REST API request is stateless, in my PHP code, how can I pass cookies at the first attempt

```
http://store12.com:8080/business?key=23122312 //i need to pass cookie during this stage
```

So, that additional API calls will work even without passing API key?

Comment: hmmm ... unless the api provider gave you specific api's to get/set cookie, maybe **[this could be useful](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265)** . ymmv, i have no experience with this specific aspect of api protocol handling, and not certain of where the RFC stands in terms of use/adoption.

Comment: Use a cookiejar to store/send cookies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used CURL, set cookie jar to pass the API, in accordance with this repository - https://github.com/dhiraj1site/restapicookieauth

I set the next endpoints as suggested and it finally worked. The directory should exist first for the curl to work. If the directory of cookie store does not exist it won't work.